# How to combine two arrays into a usable cfquery, or similar solution?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016, cfquery

I have two arrays being passed as form variables from a report page to a print page. These arrays are built as the user goes through the report, and checks checkboxes. I need to do a query based on the two arrays.  One array contains numbers, the other array contains database table names.  There is no current size limit for the array, but I don't see it ever going over 100 values, so I can say the number of array values in each array will always be equal, but could range from 1 - 100 values.  My problem is that the tables array contains a list of tables, with many repeating values.  The number that goes with each table is at the same index of the tables array as the number it goes with in the numbers array, so they're matched on idex.

So something like this:

```
NUMBERS {1, 5, 15, 8}

TABLES {THISTAB1, THISTAB1, THISTAB2, THISTAB3}
```

Is there a way to combine these two into a query-able object?  I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
<cfquery>
    SELECT NUMBERS FROM CREATEDQUERY
    WHERE TABLENAME = THISTAB1
</cfquery>
```

Using the sample data, the result set should be something like this:

```
Results {1,5}
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: Information on creating query objects: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/querynew.html

Comment: I wish I I could see more of the data in the tables. Can you do a cfdump of them?

Comment: I realize the above is a simplification, but we need more details to determine if there's a better approach. Could you provide a better example of the data you'd like to query, include a few columns so we can understand the relationships and how you're querying the data. 1. Post a sanitized sample of the data in a few of the tables (THISTAB1, THISTAB2, THISTAB3) 2. ... And the expected result.  3. *"...the result set should be something like this..."* What about the other two tables in the array? Should that data be included in the results as well, if so how?

Comment: I'll chime in with my regular security flag here, but it looks like you are performing dynamic-ish queries. You'll likely want to do a lot of validation on those arrays to make sure that the user is allowed to query the objects you're letting them query. Are the numbers a reference to a column position? ie `SELECT 3 FROM someTable`? And is `CREATEDQUERY` a table that contains text of queries that you want to run? I'm not sure of the structure of what you are trying to do here, but I would caution querying a column by a position number instead of by a specific column name.

Comment: Also, I'm concerned this may be an XY Problem. Take it a step back and detail what you are trying to accomplish rather than how you want the solution to look.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a struct with table name keys and arrays or lists of numbers. This is straight forward but also more performant if there is any concern arises for that. Based on my experience "query of query" is very slow so if you need to loop through and run many of them then this is a better choice.

```
<cfset tableData = {} />
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(tables)#" index="t">
    <cfif not structKeyExists(tableData, tables[t])>
        <cfseet tableData[tables[t]] = [] />
    </cfif>
    <cfset arrayAppend(tableData[tables[t]], numbers[t] />  
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#tableData[THISTAB1]#</cfoutput>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows, in case anyone else runs into this issue:

Create a query, you have to have at least one column, so I just added an empty one.

```
<cfset newqueryname = QueryNew("anyval", "Integer")>
```

Then add the array data as a new column,

```
<cfset QueryAddColumn(newqueryname, "numbers", "integer", NUMBERS)>
<cfset QueryAddColumn(newqueryname, "tables", "varchar", TABLES)>
```

From there you have a query you can actually use.

```
    <cfquery name="differentqueryname" dbtype="query">
        select numbers from newqueryname where
        tables = 'TABLE_NAME'
    </cfquery>

Results {1,5}
```

I appreciate those who took the time to answer, but there is a big problem with Stack Overflow.  I could ask how to create a simple if statement in Java, and 5 people would comment saying they needed more information before they could answer the question. What new information has been produced, yet I was able to answer this question?  How would it have been beneficial for me to explain every detail of a project I've been working on for the better part of 2 years, or to show a dump of every value in my database, just so someone could tell me how to use QueryAddColumn?  Not all questions are cryptic, and this one was pretty straightforward.  Try to think with the information provided to you, some people are working with sensitive data, and in my case, sharing my code is the quickest way for me to become unemployed.  I feel that this happens a lot on Stack Overflow, and 9 times out of 10, I don't think people are trying to hide anything from you, they're just trying to protect themselves.

Hope this is helpful to someone in the future.

Comment: I just posted an answer which is my go to for this sort of thing over the years. I didn't need more info after reading your question but I think part of the concern of others was that you were trying to build up a query with the table used based on user input which is a big red flag. If your question had been more general and had been Fruit or something like that instead of TableName it probably would have been answered more quickly.